# Mapping Nested Tree With Doctrine 2 and YAML

Tags: doctrine-orm, tree, doctrine, yaml

We are currently working on implementing a nested tree using the [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/tree.md) module. We believe we have wired everything up correctly, however when we go to flush using Doctrine, we keep getting an Exception.

```
SyntaxErrorException in AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 90: An exception         
occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO ProductTree (left, right,     
rootProductTreeID, level, componentProductComponentID) VALUES (?, ?, ?, 
?, ?)':

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'left, 
right, rootProductTreeID, level, componentProductComponentID) VALUES (?, 
?' at line 1
```

The code we are using that is triggering this problem is

```
$productTree->setRootProductComponentID($productComponent->getID());
$productTree->setComponent($productComponent);

$em->persist($productTree); 
$em->flush();
```

And our YAML mapping looks as so

```
OS\Domain\Entity\Products\ProductTree:
    type: entity
    repositoryClass: Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository
    table: ProductTree
    gedmo:
      tree:
        type: nested
    indexes:
        rootProductFK_idx:
            columns:
                - rootProductComponentID
        componentProductFK_idx:
            columns:
                - componentProductComponentID
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        left:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            gedmo:
              - treeLeft
        right:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            gedmo:
              - treeRight
        rootProductTreeID:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            options:
                unsigned: false
            gedmo:
              - treeRoot
        level:
            type: integer
            gedmo:
              - treeLevel
    manyToOne:
#        parent:
#            targetEntity: OS\Domain\Entity\Products\ProductComponent
#            inversedBy: children
#            joinColumn:
#              name: parentProductComponentID
#              referencedColumnName: id
#              onDelete: CASCADE
#            gedmo:
#              - treeParent
        root:
            targetEntity: OS\Domain\Entity\Products\ProductTree
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                rootProductTreeID:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
            gedmo:
              - treeParent
        component:
            targetEntity: OS\Domain\Entity\Products\ProductComponent
            cascade: {  }
            fetch: LAZY
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                componentProductComponentID:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    oneToMany:
      children:
        targetEntity: OS\Domain\Entity\Products\ProductComponent
        mappedBy: parent
        orderBy:
          left: ASC
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

Our configuration of Doctrine adds in the Tree Driver:

```
                  $metadataDriver = new MappingDriverChain();
                $configuredDriver = $this->createMetadataDriver($doctrineConfig, $metadataConfig);
                $treeDriver = $doctrineConfig->newDefaultAnnotationDriver(
                    '/vendor/gedmo/doctrine-extensions/lib/Gedmo/Tree/Entity'
                );
                $metadataDriver->addDriver($configuredDriver,'OS');
                $metadataDriver->addDriver($treeDriver,'Gedmo');
                DoctrineExtensions::registerAbstractMappingIntoDriverChainORM($metadataDriver);
```

and we register the tree listener before creating the Doctrine Entity Manager:

```
                $eventManager->addEventSubscriber(new TreeListener());

            return EntityManager::create(config('doctrine.connection'), $doctrineConfig, $eventManager);
```

We've been trying for hours to get this thing wired up, but it always fails on persistence and we can't find why. We've code traced through all the different elements, but we can't see where we are getting this error from. Any help would be much appreciated, or a sample of how we can wire up the Tree using YAML would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found that in the Tree mapping file, we had to name the left: and right: columns as lft: and rgt:, identically to the examples on the github repository for the yaml mappings.

```
fields:
    lft: <----
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        gedmo:
          - treeLeft
    rgt: <-----
        type: integer
        nullable: false
        options:
            unsigned: false
        gedmo:
          - treeRight
```